# How to speed up simulation in R

Tags: r, function, loops, simulation

Below I have a code which attempts to find an unknown equilibrium price distribution (I hope the details are not important - this is a game-theoretic economics problem) using a crude evolutionary algorithm (as found in the main loop).

However, the code runs relatively slowly, and I'm not sure how to make it more efficient. I suspect that the function "profit_p1" could be written in a vector based manner such that the function "profit_all" using sapply can be avoided.

I'm not a programmer and mainly use R for writing quick simulations, so please bear with me. If anybody could give me a hint, I would greatly appreciate it. Many thanks in advance!

```
al <- 0.4           #Parameter constraints: al >= ah > 0; al + ah < 1
ah <- 0.3           #

R0 <- al*(1-al)/(ah*(1-ah)) #Calculate relevant boundaries for R=PH/PL: R0 and R1
R1 <- (1-al)/ah             #

grid <- seq(0.01, 1, 0.01)  #Sets up a grid on the relevant interval [0,1] (100 points currently)
iter <- 10000000            #Maximal number of iterations

l <- length(grid)           #Calculate number of points in grid
pfreq <- rep(1/l, l)        #Initial guess for (symmetric) first-period price distribution: uniform over grid

#--------------------

profit_p1 <- function(p1)   #Function that gives expected profit for arbitrary price in grid
    {
    x <- sum(pfreq[grid < p1/R0])*ah*p1 +
         (1-al)*al/(1-ah) * sum(pfreq[(grid >= p1/R0 & grid < p1)]*grid[(grid >= p1/R0 & grid < p1)]) +
         (al+ah)/2 * p1 * sum(pfreq[abs(grid-p1)<0.0001]) +
         al*p1*sum(pfreq[grid > p1 & grid <= p1*R0]) +
         (1-ah)*ah/(1-al) * sum(pfreq[(grid > p1*R0 & grid <= p1*R1)]*grid[(grid > p1*R0 & grid <= p1*R1)]) +
         (1-ah)*p1 * sum(pfreq[grid > p1*R1])
    return(x)
    }

profit_all <- function()    #Function that gives expected profit for all prices in grid
    {
    return(sapply(grid,profit_p1))
    }

#--------------------

for(count in 1:iter)        #Main loop
{

pfreq[which.max(profit_all())] <- pfreq[which.max(profit_all())] + 0.0001   # The freq. of the grid point which yields the highest expected profit is increased slightly
pfreq <- pfreq / sum(pfreq)                         # But of course, the total probability mass must sum up to 1

#--------------------

if(count %% 100 == 0)                               # Display price distribution and expected profits after every 100 iterations
{
plot(grid, profit_all(), ylim = c(0,0.5), type="l")
lines(grid, pfreq / max(pfreq)*0.4, col="orange")
}

#--------------------

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure on if or how to vectorize `profit_all`, but you can at least avoid having to compute `profit_all()` multiple times in each iteration. In your main for loop, just cache your result in the first line as `result <- profit_all()` instead of evaluating the function 3 separate times per iteration. That should speed up your program by a factor of 2 at least. However, 10^7 iterations will still take far too long to be practical. Are you sure you need that many iterations? From my brief testing of your code, the plotted lines seem to settle by a few thousand iterations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that led to a nice improvement. No, I definitely don't need that many iterations.... 10^4 should be fine usually. However, it would be great if the whole thing could be sped up, as I could then go for finer grid sizes.

Comment: You can eke out even more speed by using `gridcond1 <- grid >= p1/R0 & grid < p1` and `gridcond2 <- grid > p1*R0 & grid <= p1*R1` indexing the `pfreq` and `grid` arrays in `profit_p1`.  You should also have a look at the `compiler` package and use a compiled version of `profit_p1`. The speedup is not spectacular but is does help.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will check that out tomorrow. I'll try to report back.